# Inconsistency in Plot3D and RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, inequalities

New user of Mathematica here. I am trying to understand what is going on with the output of Plot3D and RegionPlot since the two seem inconsistent:

$\pi_u = \frac{(d_u-1) (d_u+1)^2}{16 \left(2 \alpha d_u^2 (\xi-1)+d_u-1\right)}$;
$\pi_c = -\frac{1}{2} (d_c-1) d (\alpha d_c (\xi-1)+1)$

Trying to assess the region where one is larger than the other.

```
piu = ((-1 + du1) (1 + du1)^2)/(16 (-1 + du1 + 2 alpha du1^2 (-1 + xi)))
du1 = Root[
  1 + (-2 - 2 alpha + 2 alpha xi) #1 + (1 + alpha - 
       alpha xi) #1^2 + (-alpha + alpha xi) #1^3 &, 1]
du1 = Simplify[ToRadicals[du1]]
dc2 = (-1 - alpha + alpha xi + Sqrt[
  1 - alpha + alpha^2 + alpha xi - 2 alpha^2 xi + alpha^2 xi^2])/(
 3 (-alpha + alpha xi))
pic=-(1/2) (-1 + dc2) dc2 (1 + alpha dc2 (-1 + xi))
Plot3D[{((-1 + du1) (1 + du1)^2)/(
  16 (-1 + du1 + 2 alpha du1^2 (-1 + xi))), -(1/
    2) (-1 + dc2) dc2 (1 + alpha dc2 (-1 + xi))}, {alpha, 0, 1}, {xi, 
  0, 1}]
RegionPlot[{((-1 + du1) (1 + du1)^2)/(
   16 (-1 + du1 - 2 alpha du1^2 (-1 + xi))) >= -(1/
     2) (-1 + dc2) dc2 (1 + alpha dc2 (-1 + xi))}, {alpha, 0, 1}, {xi,
   0, 1}]
```

[image]
[image]

What is(are) the error(s)? Reduce is taking forever. How can I find the area such that $\pi_u\geq\pi_c$? Please be kind.

Comment: Go to help function/manual to see under Posible Issues of ToRadicals: "ToRadicals converts Root objects containing parameters:  ...The result may not be equal to the Root object for some values of the parameter: ..."  Just omitt  the step with ToRadicals.

Comment: Thank you, regionPlot changed by skipping the ToRadicals step, yet the plots remain inconsistent.

Comment: `Reduce[{piu >= pic, 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 <= xi <= 1}, {alpha, xi}]` evaluates to `0 < alpha <= 1 && 0 <= xi < 1`, i.e., the entire plot region except `alpha == 0` and `xi == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an answer to the question. Somewhat extending the @BobHanlon comment,

```
du1 = Root[1 + (-2 - 2 alpha + 2 alpha xi) #1 + (1 + alpha - 
alpha xi) #1^2 + (-alpha + alpha xi) #1^3 &, 1];
dc2 = (-1 - alpha + alpha xi + 
Sqrt[1 - alpha + alpha^2 + alpha xi - 2 alpha^2 xi + 
alpha^2 xi^2])/(3 (-alpha + alpha xi));
pic = -(1/2) (-1 + dc2) dc2 (1 + alpha dc2 (-1 + xi));
piu = ((-1 + du1) (1 + du1)^2)/(16 (-1 + du1 + 
2 alpha du1^2 (-1 + xi)));
Reduce[{piu >= pic, 0 <= alpha, 0 <= xi}, {alpha, xi}]
```

> `alpha > 0 && 0 <= xi < 1`

Its numeric verification

```
values = FindInstance[ piu >= pic && alpha >= 0 && alpha <= 10 && xi >= 0 && 
xi <= 10, {alpha, xi}, Reals, 10000];
points = Table[{alpha, xi} /. values[[j]], {j, 1, 10000}];
ListPlot[points]
```

[image]